# C++ in Linux: In what forked-task context should a timer callback execute?

Tags: c++, linux, callback, fork

I have implemented my own Timer/Callback classes in C/C++ in Linux, wherein a process requiring a timer to fire either ONE_SHOT or PERIODICally instantiates a timer, and instantiates a callback object and associates the callback with previously created Timer object. The Callback class implements a triggered () method, and when the timer fires at the appointed timeout, the triggered () method is executed. (Nothing new in terms of functionality.) The way my Timer class works is I maintain a minheap of Timer objects and thus always know which timer to fire next. There is a timer task (TimerTask) which itself runs as a separate process (created using fork ()) and shares the memory pools from which the Timer objects and the Callback objects are created. The TimerTask has a main while (1) loop which keeps checking if the root of the Timer object minheap has a time since epoch that is LEQ the current time since epoch. If so, the timer at root has "fired."

Currently, when the timer fires, the callback is executed in the TimerTask process context. I am currently changing this behavior to run the callback processing on other tasks (send them the information that the Timer object has fired via a POSIX message queue. For example, send the message to the Timer object creating process), but my question to SO is what are the principles behind this? Executing a callback in the TimerTask context seems like a bad idea if I expect to service a large number of timers. It seems like a good idea to dispatch the callback processing over to other processes.

What are the general rules of thumb for processing the callback in one task/process over the other? My intention is to process the callback in the receiving task using a pthread like so:

```
void threadFunctionForTimerCallback (void* arg)
{
    while (1)
    {
      if ((mq_receive (msg_fd, buffer, attr.mq_msgsize, NULL)) == -1)
    exit (-1);
      else
    printf ("Message received %s\n", buffer);
    }
}
```

Would this be a reasonable solution? But never mind the actual way of receiving the message from the TimerTask (threads or any other method, doesn't matter), any discussion and insight into the problem of assigning a task for the callback is appreciated.

Comment: Why does the timer dispatching code run in a separate process? Can it not run in the same process?

Comment: That is my design. I want a multi-tasking environment where several important aspects of robust carrier grade software run as separate processes. E.g., logging is its own process, timer management is its own process, configuration management is its own process, CLI is its own process etc. Most importantly, I cannot have a busy waiting on the main process that does a host of other things. And I don't want these to be separate threads.

Comment: I'm probably missing the point here one way or another, but presumably the timer callback is expected to do some particular task (i.e. it's not just executing the callback for no reason), and therefore the best place for that callback to execute would be inside the process that is in charge of doing that task, so that it has direct access to the objects it needs to interact with?

Comment: FWIW using multiple processes that share memory isn't all that much safer than just using threads; in either scenario you have the potential for race conditions, deadlocks, erroneous memory overwrites, etc.  If you're going to use multiple processes for safety's sake, you might want to just go all the way and use only messaging with no shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to busy spin `while(1)` to implement a timer. One traditional and robust way of implementing timers has been using minheap as you do to organize times to expiry and then pass the time till the next timer expiry as a timeout argument to `select()` or `epoll()`. Using `select()` call a thread can watch for file descriptor readiness, signals and timers all at the same time.

Recent kernels support [`timerfd`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) that delivers timer expiry events as file descriptor readiness for read which again can be handled using `select()/epoll()`. It obviates the need to maintain the minheap, however, requires a system call for each add/modify/delete a timer.

Having timer code in another process requires processes to use inter-process communication mechanisms, thereby introducing more complexity, so it can actually make the system less robust, especially when the processes communicate via shared memory and can corrupt it.

Anyway, one can use Unix domain sockets to send messages back and forth between communicating processes on the same host. Again, `select()/epoll()` are your best friends. Or a more high level framework can be used for message passing, such as [0MQ](http://api.zeromq.org/).

Comment: Sorry, but this is really off topic. I am aware of all the goodness select and poll can do, but my question is about something else. As I noted several times, the method of delivering the message to the processing task/thread is of no interest to me. I know of the many ways to do it.

Comment: Oh... It's just that using obsolete System V message queues along with shared memory for messaging doesn't sound like an informed choice to me.

Comment: And I am not using System V queues, clearly, given my mq_receive () choice. Please read the question! This is not an answer. My question is about task contexts, not which message queue to use.